# using gridview inside a runnable gives error

Tags: android, gridview, timer, handler, runnable

Can somebody explain how to use the `GridView` inside a `Runnable`.

```
Handler starthandler = new Handler();
Runnable startrun= new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        G1=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.balloongrid);
        G1.setAdapter(new BalloonImageAdaper(this)); 
    }
};
```

The above code gives the following error:

> The constructor Cacrballoonclass.BalloonImageAdaper(new Runnable(){}) is  undefined

```
        public class BalloonImageAdaper extends BaseAdapter{ // create a class by name 
        imageadapter so as to fill the gridview with data

    private Context ballooncontext;


     public BalloonImageAdaper (Context c) {
            ballooncontext = c;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return balloonthumbs.length; 
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView balloonimageview;

         if(arg1==null){
            balloonimageview = new ImageView(ballooncontext);
            balloonimageview.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(75,75));
            balloonimageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            balloonimageview.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
        }else {
                balloonimageview = (ImageView)arg1;
                }
        // lets inflate balloon randomly

     int rballoon = new Random().nextInt(ballooninstruct.length);   

              balloonimageview.setImageResource(balloonthumbs[rballoon]);            

               balloonimageview.setTag(balloonthumbs[rballoon]);

    return balloonimageview;
    }

}// class imageAdapter extends baseadapter

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    finish();
} 

      }//class ends cacrballoonclasss
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
new BalloonImageAdaper(this)
```

with

```
new BalloonImageAdaper(mContext) // mContext: reference to any Context (Activity or whatever)
```

(If that's inside an `Activity` you can use `NameOfActivity.this`.)

The `this` inside your `Runnable` is referring to your `Runnable` and not, like I assume you want it to reference to, your `Activity`.

Comment: dear Ahmad, thank you for the reply. i look into it and try to apply changes.

Comment: still same error...could not resolve to variable...i am using the context that is in balloonimageadapter class

Comment: please look at the code ..i have added the balloonimageadapter class above in the code..